# Altova Mapforce- Could not find start of message error

Tags: sql-server, mapping, edi, altova, x12

I am using Altomava Mapforce to map and load 837 x12 formatted text files directly to Sql Server 2014.  I have correctly mapped everything except I get the following errors-

1. Missing field F142- Application Senders code
2. Could not find start of message with impl.convention reference '116731H333B2'.  Message will be skipped.
3. Missing segment GE

I have included my header and footer information below from the original source text file.  Does anyone know what is going on with the mapping, or if maybe there is something wrong with the data itself?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Header-**

```
ISA*11*          *11*          *PP*               *ZZ*20121143      *273041*0109*^*00501*000000000*0*T*:~GS*HC**211231153*20141121*1115*01*Y*116731H333B2~ST*837*2000001*116731H333B2~BHT*0029*00*0003000005*20141121*1115*CH
```

**Message Data etc.......**

**Footer-**

```
~SE*769*2000001~GE*1*01~IEA*1*000000000~
```

Comment: There is no GS02 - that's the problem with #1.  Not sure why they aren't sending the Group Sender.  In fact, the whole GS is missing elements like version.  (#2). The GE is probably checking against the GS which is screwed up. (#3).  Download EDI Notepad from Liaison for free.

Comment: I just checked out Liasons software this really helps me understand whats missing thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is wrong.  Here is a cleaned up version of the ISA / GS. For readability, I put a CR/LF after the segment terminator (~).  Please note the ISA and GS do not indicate sender, which is going to cause all kinds of problems for auditing.   See my comment above for analysis on the data per your bullet points.

```
ISA*11*          *11*          *PP*SENDER         *ZZ*20121143      *273041*0109*^*00501*000000000*0*T*:~
GS*HC*SENDER*211231153*20141121*1115*01*X*005010~
ST*837*2000001*116731H333B2~
BHT*0029*00*0003000005*20141121*1115*CH
```

An example of the enveloping:

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*Test1Saver     *ZZ*RECEIVER       *151222*1932*U*00501*000111884*0*P*:~GS*HC*Test1Saver*RECEIVER*20151222*1932*1*X*005010~ST*850*0001~
...
~SE*8*0001~GE*1*1~IEA*1*000111884~
```

Comment: I will try manually editing the data this afternoon.  Once I test it and figure out any further data discrepancies I can go back to the vendor with my findings and ask for changes to the data extract.  Once I test this change I'll be sure to give you a +1, thanks!

Comment: Adding a test sender value did the trick for number one, but the main issue is it still is skipping the entire message portion for some reason.  Do you by chance have a sample header /footer section i could use for an example?  I'm new to x12 formatting, thanks.  I'm not sure what the issue with the GS section is

Answer (score 0):

If, 123456789 have value then map 123456789 and if  having null or blank or no value then send default 123.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/083ND.png)